# Ubuntu 13.04 random lockup - Xorg dying, colored squares

Tags: xorg

I've installed Ubuntu 13.04 on an Acer nettop and randomly, Ubuntu locks up and the screen looks like this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/y6t3npxqvbi3zvh/ubuntu_lockup.jpg

Desperately need help. Any advice? Video card is an NVIDIA Ion GT128.

Comment: What graphics card are you using?

Comment: NVIDIA Ion GT128.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the Nvidia drivers might solve your problem:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Interesting! Nothing was purged, it said nothing existed. So now I'm installing nvidia-current. I'm at my dad's place installing Ubuntu for him, and this is not making a great use case for him. ;) I've never seen it do this before. I'll give this a shot and see how it goes.

Comment: Having graphics drivers is always a good thing ;)

Comment: Bah! Overrated! ;)

Comment: Uh oh. Now my sound is totally dead! Graphics seem OK. In Sound prefs, there are no output devices.

Comment: Hmm, since sound issues do have have anything to do with this question, I suggest you create a new question about the sound issues and accept this as an answer.

Comment: Oh NVM, just a weird glitch. Rebooted, sound is OK. AND now I have 5.1 surround which wasn't working before!!